# docker-compose in windows: Unsupported config option for services: 'web'

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-compose

I am trying to setup my first docker compose complete application, and I have created a spring boot application that depends on mongodb. So, I have created a docker-compose.yml file at the root of my code, at the same level of Dockerfile. When I create the image using `gradlew build buildDocker` everuthing goes fine, and the image is created and I can run it (but it fails because it cannot open mongodb connection). So, I created the docker-compose.yml this way:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    environment:
      spring.data.mongodb.host: localhost
      spring.data.mongodb.port: 27017
      spring.data.mongodb.database: Transactions
      spring.data.mongodb.username: someUsername
      spring.data.mongodb.password: somePassword
    image: "mongo:3.4"
```

However, when I execute `docker-compose up` command, I get this error:

```
Unsupported config option for services: 'web'
```

I am using Windows 10 as O.S., and the version of docker compose is `docker-compose version 1.14.0, build c7bdf9e3`

Question:
Does anyone knows how do I need to setup the docker-compose.yml file in order to not receive that error?

Comment: Try setting the docker-compose version number at the 1st line, e.g. `version: '2'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @fernandezcuesta said,
**You need to add version number for each docker-compose file.**

Example :

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    environment:
      spring.data.mongodb.host: localhost
      spring.data.mongodb.port: 27017
      spring.data.mongodb.database: Transactions
      spring.data.mongodb.username: someUsername
      spring.data.mongodb.password: somePassword
    image: "mongo:3.4"
```

See [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) for more details.